# Powershell script to get the list of items created/modified on particular day

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

We would like to pass the particular day and get the list of items changed on that day. Do we have any PowerShell script for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$startDate = [DateTime]"2023-1-01"
$endDate = [DateTime]"2023-1-12"

Get-ChildItem -Path "master" -ID "ITEM ID here" -Recurse |  Where-Object { ($_.__Updated).Date -ge $startDate -and ($_.__Updated).Date -lt $endDate} | Select-Object -Property Name, __Updated, @{Label="Path"; Expression={$_.Paths.FullPath}}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you install the Sitecore PowerShell, there is already a similar script that performs the task you required. It is found at the following path: `/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SPE/Reporting/Content Reports/Reports/Content Audit/Items last updated`.

When you run the script, it allows you

- To pick up a date and time.
- Pick whether the items should have been last updated before or after the specified date.

Below is a screenshot of the dialog that appears when you run the script

[image]

Note that you can customize the script to incorporate your additional requirements and as a best practice, it is better if you duplicate the script before making any changes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simple PowerShell script, that you can use to filter by Date.

In the example below, I am trying to get all the items under Home Item by passing the item Id.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "master" -ID "{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}" -Recurse |  Where-Object { ($_.__Created).Date -eq [datetime]::Today} | Select-Object -Property Name, __Created
```

The Sitecore item field that I am using to compare is the `__Created`

So it will give me all the items that I have created today in the result like this.

[image]

You can extend it as per your needs.

Thanks